# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView not Work

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I use react-navigation and stack navigator. Same time I want use keyboardavoidingview all stack screen. Bu keyboardavoidingview not working any page.
Code :

```js
    <NavigationContainer>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{flex:1}}
        behavior = { Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        />
        <StackNavigator>
        <StackScreen ..... />
        <StackScreen ..... />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
   </NavigationContainer>
```

I've looked almost everywhere and can't find anything.

Comment: you can't do it that way.

Comment: How can I do it. Can you help

Comment: Why don't you wrap the ```KeyboardAvoidingView``` in the component of the ```StackScreen``` instead the ```NavigationContainer```??

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a wrapper for `View` which then can be reused for all other components. I will call it `BaseView`.

```js
export function BaseView({children, style}) {
  return <KeyboardAvoidingView style={[{flex: 1}, style]} behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>{children}</KeyboardAvoidingView >
}
```

Then, reuse it for other screens.

```js
export function ScreenA(props) {
    return <BaseView> ... </BaseView>
}
```

`ScreenA` could be any screen, e.g. a screen defined in your navigator.

The above has the advantage that the configuration of `KeyboardAvoidingView` is the same for all screens and can be configured for all in a single component. Furthermore, if you decide to replace your Keyboardavoiding handling in the future, then it is easy to replace your current implementation.